# Adding execArgs to Node executable using child_process.spawn

Tags: node.js

I am wondering what the correct way is to add "execArgs" to a Node process -

we have:

```
const cp = require('child_process');

const n = cp.spawn('node', ['some-file.js'], {});
```

but what if I want to add an execArg like so:

```
const n = cp.spawn('node --harmony', ['some-file.js'], {});
```

I don't think that is the right way to do it, and the docs don't seem to demonstrate this?

Is this the correct way?

```
 const n = cp.spawn('node', ['--harmony','some-file.js'], {});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs for `child_process.spawn()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/v6.2.0/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) it clearly states that args is an array of string arguments that is passed in as the second argument.

> The child_process.spawn() method spawns a new process using the given command, with command line arguments in args. If omitted, args defaults to an empty array.
>
> A third argument may be used to specify additional options, with these defaults:
>
> `{ cwd: undefined, env: process.env }`

#### Example of running ls -lh /usr, capturing stdout, stderr, and the exit code:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

ls.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

Based on the above pulled from the child_process docs, the below would be correct.

`const n = cp.spawn('node', ['--harmony','some-file.js']);`